# Magento 2 Admin Page Error: Your current session has been expired

Tags: session, admin-panel, magento2.2.2

Fresh Install of Magento 2.2.2 on Centos (Plesk) with Apache 2.4, php 7.0.2 + all modules, mariaDb 10.1.

Magento Installation was done via browser wizard -> readyness check-> everything was ok. When I try to login to the Magento Admin Page "Your current session has been expired." is always showing.

I am running Magento 2.1.7 on this Server and had the same problem. But I solved this problem by changing one line of Timezone.php (shown in here  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5383). However with Magento 2.2.2 this solution does not work anymore.

Any Ideas how to solve this ?

Ps: Already cleared cache folders and cache via cli.

When I run "php -v" via SSH --> php 7.0.27 is shown

I configured Php 7 (via Plesk) for scripts on my domain 
"/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -v" --> shows php 7

BUT phpMyAdmin (login to mariaDB) shows this (php 5.6.30):
[image]

Maybe this is causing the error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> - Find path `admin/security/session_lifetime` in `core_config_data` table
> - If it's present then set its value to `86400`
> - If that path is not present then add it with value `86400`

```
    INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
    VALUES ('default', 0, 'admin/security/session_lifetime', '86400');
```

> After that, refresh Magento cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cache and login to admin.

> rm -rf var/cache/*
>
> rm -rf var/page_cache/*
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

I had enabled Magento Profiler before by adding 'SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"' to my .htaccess. After removing this line again, the error stopped and I can access the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for **Magento ≥ 2.3.7**:

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0
bin/magento cache:clean
```

[mage2.pro/t/6362](https://mage2.pro/t/6362)

Another message for the same error is «[**Session size of** <…> **exceeded allowed session max size of** <…>](https://mage2.pro/t/6363)»