# Set Lifetime Session but Around a Week Expired Session--AGAIN and AGAIN in Magento 2.2.4

Tags: admin, session, magento2.2.4

i want to set lifetime session but after around 1 week session has expired

**session.gc_maxlifetime 31536000**  and Adding

**admin/security/session lifetime to 31536000 in core_config_data** but still issue session expire in magento 2.2

I didn't delete cookies  I want to make it for a lifetime.

Any Suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Any error logs ?

Comment: Nothing in error logs

Comment: Your Magento version and where is the Magento hosted?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.4